# unexpected output in php while using `!`

Tags: php

I was just trying an small program but i am getting unexpected output.

```
for($i=20;!$i<20;$i--)
echo '*';
```

the expected output is `*` as only for first case when `$i=20` is false so `!$i<20` should return true but the no of times loop is executing is equal to value of `$i`.

I tried manipulating values and concluded when I set value of `$i` in negative the loop gets infinite.

Further i tried this

```
echo 20<20;
```

output was nothing as expected
then

```
echo !20<20;
```

output was `1` as expected

Now when it tried:

```
19<20
```

it is returning 1 but when i am trying

```
!19<20
```

it is returning `1`
why did this occurred ??
I am running PHP on WAMP Server and my PHP Version `5.5.0`

**Note:** I am not having any problem with for loop i can handle it so please don't answer correcting my loop rather I was confused with working of `!` so please answer for it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need brackets to 'not' the right part:

```
for($i=20;!($i<20);$i--)
  echo '*';
```

The example of `!20<20` does this:

```
!20<20
!(true)<20  <- converts the type to bool so we can negate
false<20    <- negates the true to false
0<20        <- converts the false to an int to compare
true
```

And the example of `!19<20` does this:

```
!19<20
!(true)<20  <- converts the type to bool so we can negate
false<20    <- negates the true to false
0<20        <- converts the false to an int to compare
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for($i=20;!($i<20);$i--)
echo '*';
```

Problem was that '!$i' were executing first and then '<' operator work.